# Redirecting to a page via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to Ajaxify a normal page redirect.

ASPX (View: Parent.aspx):

```
<a id="GetContent" href="#">Go to Content Page</a>
```

ASPX (View: Content.aspx):

```
<div id="content">
   ...
</div>
```

Controller (ContentController.cs):

```
public ActionResult Index(id)
{
    var content = _db.GetContent(id);
    return View("Content");
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", "#GetContent", function () {
        location.href = "/Index/3";
});
```

I tried this.  This works, however, the url in the URL bar does not change.

```
$(document).on("click", "#GetContent", function () {
           $("#content").load("/Index/3");
    });
```

So when you click on the link, currently it posts back normally and then redirects to ~/Content/3 (i.e. no ajax).  What I want is to immediately go to the Content page, and then display a loading indicator while the content is being fetched.  I know I probably have to use jQuery.load() to do this, but not quite sure how to put things together.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just add the ajax function on the page you're redirecting to ?

Comment: I'm not able to figure out where to add that using ASP.NET MVC. The onclick logic is in the js file as noted.

Comment: @adeneo I updated my question.  I tried using .load() but the url in the URL bar stays the same, does not change to the new URL.  Is there anyway to still show the new URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking to do...

Index.aspx:

```
<div id="content">
   ...
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/Content/Details/3', // <-- Can use @Html.ActionLink here, to utilize routing a bit.
        success: function(data) {
          $('#content').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

ContentController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index(id)
{
    return View("Index");
}

public ActionResult Details(id)
{
    var content = _db.GetContent(id);
    return PartialView("_Details", content);
}
```

If you put a loader.gif in the div initially I think you'll get the behavior you are looking for. You'll also need to make sure you have the _Details view created, and displaying whatever is in your model (**var content**).

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of what I had in mind, but just couldn't get it together.  Will give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

i would link jquery (through

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

) and then use

```
var checking = "<img src='ajax-loader.gif'/>";
$("#content").innerHTML=checking
$("#content").load("/content/3");
```

to load it in the page